# Using key combinations in .vimrc

Tags: vim, config

```
imap ( ()<ESC>i
imap { {<CR> <CR>}<ESC>i<Up><Tab>
imap [ []<ESC>i
imap <S-BS> <Del>
```

I decided to create auto bracket and there I was a need key combination for fast delete double bracket (4 line in code). But it doesn't work. What's the problem? It work if I overwrite `<S-BS>` to (for example) symbol `*`.

Comment: Vim doesn't see `<S-BS>` so that mapping will never work. You will have to find another one.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `<S-BS>`, Vim sees `<BS>`. To verify this, do `CTRL-V` then backspace or shift+backspace in insert mode. This will insert `^?` for both, which is the terminal code for those special keys. See `:help c_CTRL-V`. So both backspace and shift+backspace have the same terminal code, which means Vim can't tell the difference between the two.

The mapping does work in gVim though.